# Maven find files in dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, jacoco

I have two projects **A** and **B**. Project **B** have dependency of project **A**. In both there is jacoco xml report. When project B is building I need to find jacoco xml reports from A and B projects, make some stuff and save the result in B output directory. I broke my head looking for a solution. How I can achive my goal?

Comment: Your jacoco report is packed into the jar?

Comment: @JFMeier, yesss

Comment: What does a code coverage report do in a jar? What is it meant for when you use the jar in production?

Comment: Actually the real thing I need to do is in B project count code coverage of B and his dependency (A project) and save the result into property file. Next this property file will be reading by some service and show info by API. In other words I need to aggregate code coverage info during build B project.

Comment: Frankly, this all sounds like a strange idea. Usually, you don't put reports into jars, and you don't try to find reports of dependencies. What is the purpose of this "service" that you want to build?

Comment: I agree but analysts want to be able to get coverage information on an api